# Can asymptotic approximations of terms be used to give asymptotic approximations of a sum?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

Let $a_n \sim b_n$,

More formally I mean, $\displaystyle{} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$

Would that then imply that for some $n_0$, $\displaystyle{} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \cfrac{\sum_{n = n_0}^{T} a_n}{\sum_{n = n_0}^{T} b_n}$ = 1,

Comment: Those two sums are both numbers, not functions ... what would $\sim$ even mean for them?

Comment: @GregMartin , you are right, I’ve updated the question to what I really mean, thank you. Please let me know if anything else is wrong or needs clarification

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n=1/n^2$,
$b_n=a_n+ 1/n^4$

They satisfy your pre-condition, but $ \sum a_n = c_1 \neq c_2 = \sum b_n$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)},\ b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}.$
If your idea worked, then the two infinite sums from some $n_0$ onward would be equal (since each sum converges). However the first sum telescopes to a rational number, while the second sum differs from $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by a rational number.

**Edit:** Even easier: since for each $n$ we have $a_n<b_n$ the sums from some point on cannot be equal.

Comment: About the edit: That's not quite true. Consider $a_n = n$ and $b_n = n+1$ - the ratio of the sum also converges despite $a_n < b_n$

Comment: In my edit the sums $\sum a_n,\ \sum b_n$ [each over $n \ge n_0$] are convergent series of positive terms for which $a_n<b_n.$ So the limiting ratio defined in the OP is that of the "tails" of the series I refer to, and that cannot be $1,$ since the sums cannot be equal.